# Error while handling Appcheck with flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage, firebase-app-check

I want to upload files in the firebase storage, but i have an error of appcheck after many researches, i saw that i have to activate Appcheck on firebase, but also to activate it on my application

in a google video on youtube, i have seen that i have to call this function while building my app:

initFirebase(){

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(/*context*/ this);
FirebaseAppCheck firebaseAppCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance();
firebaseAppCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(
SafetyNetAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance());
```

}

But i have errors, that the methods "initializeApp";"getInstance" and "installAppCheckProviderFactory" are not defined,

Answer (score 3):

Your `MainActivity.kt` shoul look like this:

```
package com.example.app //your package name

import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp
import com.google.firebase.appcheck.FirebaseAppCheck
import com.google.firebase.appcheck.debug.DebugAppCheckProviderFactory

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "samples.flutter.dev/battery"

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler {
            call, result ->
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(/*context=*/this)
            val firebaseAppCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance()
            firebaseAppCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(
                    DebugAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance()
            )
        }
    }
}
```

And your `main.dart` like this:

```
import 'package:firebase_app_check/firebase_app_check.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate();
}
```