# firebase/flutter - Play Integrity - where to place the initialization code

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-play-integrity-api

I'm using this guide to implement the new app check Play Integrity: https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android/play-integrity-provider?authuser=0&hl=de#java_1

at step 3 it is mentioned to add this initialization code:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(/*context=*/ this);
FirebaseAppCheck firebaseAppCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance();
firebaseAppCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(
        PlayIntegrityAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance());
```

**But where??**

I tried it in main.dart, MainActivity.java and Application.jave with no success. Maybe I need some more packages? it would help me a lot if i know where to try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the code must be inserted in the MainActivity.java and you need additional these package (not mentioned in the google guide)

In MainActivity.java:

```
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.appcheck.FirebaseAppCheck;
import com.google.firebase.appcheck.playintegrity.PlayIntegrityAppCheckProviderFactory;
```

In pubspec.yaml:

```
firebase_app_check: ^0.1.1+8
```

this helped me: [Error while handling Appcheck with flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68433315/error-while-handling-appcheck-with-flutter)

Answer (score 1):

If you use firebase in flutter. Then I think it should help you

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
      // required line
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      // init firebase
      FirebaseApp.initializeApp();
      FirebaseAppCheck firebaseAppCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance();
      firebaseAppCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(
             PlayIntegrityAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance());
      // run app
      runApp(const MyApp()));
 }
```

Comment: thank you that helps, but then I get the error: The method 'initializeApp' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseApp'

Comment: Have you added the firebase_core library to pubspec.yaml?

Comment: sorry this doesnt work , if you think we are probably making a mistake, please provide us your main.dart file